# What is the idiomatic way to write the sine of the negative of an angle in Rust?

Tags: rust, trigonometry

Let `fi` be an f64 angle value. The sine of `-fi` can be written in rust in the following two ways

```rust
let fi : f64 = PI/2;
let s1 = (-fi).sin();
let s2 = f64::sin(-fi);
```

It seems that form 1 is more common among rust programmers. Are there practical advantages of this form, apart from style?

Edited: Changed cosine to sine for the example to make sense. Changed the question to make it more technical/factual.

Comment: Option 2 means a refactor that changes your types (e.g. from `f64` to `f32`) needs to change additional places in the code. But this is Rust, so at least you can't *forget* to make that change (unlike virtually every other language, Rust won't let `f32` and `f64` interoperate). Which leaves this pretty much opinion-based; personally, I'd use `(-fi).cos()`, but mostly due to habit from other languages where it avoids the refactoring issues; there's no strong argument either way in Rust.

Comment: Given *cos(x) = cos(-x)*, is this really an issue at all?

Comment: I think this depends on whether you actually care whether it's an `f64` or not. If someone were to switch to `f32`, _should_ that be a compiler error? Do you want to enforce the double precision? If so, use `f64::sin`; if not, use `(-fi).sin()`. (Anyway, the negativeness of the number seems secondary to the intent of the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, form 1 is going to be more common in Rust.  It may look bizarre to writers of many languages, but it seems very natural to me as a Rust and Ruby programmer.  (To be fair, Ruby uses `Math.cos(-Math::PI/2)`, but it does have many methods on `Float`.)

As mentioned in the comments, it makes refactoring easier.  If you decide to extend your code to be generic over floating-point types, such as with the num-traits crate, then it's going to be a lot nicer to work with than `T::cos(-f1)`.  As a person who hates having to change lots of things when refactoring, it seems logical to me.

This is also consistent with how other parenthesized expressions work in Rust, such as `(1..10).map(|x| x * 2)`.  Nobody really wants to write the struct name there.  As a code readability rule, if I'm in doubt, when in Rome, do as the Romans.

However, the two syntaxes are completely functionally identical, and as such this is a style decision.  As long as you're consistent and you and any collaborators are the same page, it ultimately doesn't matter.